# Perform action on Laravel model once it has been filled with data

Tags: php, json, laravel, model, laravel-5.4

So I have a model that has a json field as an attribute. When it is retrieved, I'd like to convert that field into an array so I can do some other things with it.

For example, if the json has data like this `{name:bob,email:sue}` in a parameter called `json`, when the model object is built, I'd like it to something like this:

```
public function setJsonAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['json'] = $value;
    $jsonInfo = json_decode($value, true);
    $this->name = $jsonInfo['email'];
    $this->email = $jsonInfo['name'];
}
```

This is an example of an attempt I did with a mutator, but it's not optimal. Is there any way to do this kind of thing automatically once the model has been loaded with data from the database?

Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eloquent includes a feature called array casting which converts a field from JSON to an array property on retrieval and converts the array back to a JSON string on saving.

You can enable this by adding a $casts property to your Model with the field name as the key and array as the value:

```
protected $casts = [
    'options' => 'array',
];
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

If you had `options` as `{name:bob,email:sue}` in the database, you would then access them as `$model->options['name']` and `$model->options['email']`.

Comment: Thanks, it's not entirely what I was hoping for, but this will work. Certainly a lot cleaner and less hacky-feeling than what I was cooking up.